# fopen no Authorization header with PHP 7

Tags: php, fopen, php-7, http-status-code-401, php-5.6

I have some code which makes a request to fetch data from Jive's API. I am running this code on MAMP, which allows me to run either PHP 5.6.10 or PHP 7.0.0. With PHP5, I get a successful response. With PHP 7 I get 401 Unauthorized.

The relevant function is here:

```
protected function sendRequest($method, $url, $auth = null) {
    global $CFG;
    $options = func_num_args() === 4 ? func_get_arg(3) : array();

    $http = array(
      'max_redirects' => 0,
      'request_fulluri' => 1,
      'ignore_errors' => true,
      'method' => $method,
      'header' => array()
    );

    if (!is_null($auth)) {
      array_push($http['header'], 'Authorization: ' . $auth);
    }

    if (($method === 'PUT' || $method === 'POST') && isset($options['content'])) {
      $http['content'] = $options['content'];
      array_push($http['header'], 'Content-length: ' . strlen($options['content']));
      array_push($http['header'], 'Content-Type: application/json');
    }

    var_dump($http);echo('<hr/>');

    $context = stream_context_create(array( 'http' => $http ));

    var_dump(stream_context_get_options($context));echo('<hr/>');
    $fp = fopen($url, 'rb', false, $context);
    if (! $fp) {
      throw new \Exception('Request failed: $php_errormsg');
    }
    $metadata = stream_get_meta_data($fp);
    $content  = stream_get_contents($fp);
    $responseCode = (int)explode(' ', $metadata['wrapper_data'][0])[1];

    fclose($fp);

    return array (
      'metadata' => $metadata,
      'content' => $content,
      'status' => $responseCode
    );
}
```

The var_dump calls produce the same results with both PHP versions. The response I get is:

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "wrapper_data": [
            "HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized",
            "Server: Apache",
            "X-Jive-Request-Id: 6c433c20-688a-11e6-b332-005056a4250c",
            "X-Jive-Flow-Id: 6c433c21-688a-11e6-b332-005056a4250c",
            "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN",
            "Expires: Mon, 22 Aug 2016 17:04:01 GMT",
            "Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, private, max-age=0",
            "X-JSL: D=1754 t=1471885441249342",
            "Content-Type: text/plain",
            "Date: Mon, 22 Aug 2016 17:04:01 GMT",
            "Connection: close",
            "Set-Cookie: jive.login.ts=1471885441250; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly;HttpOnly",
            "Set-Cookie: X-JCAPI-Token=pTVEn2P4; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly",
            "Set-Cookie: BIGipServerpool_sandbox.jiveon.com=25472522.20480.0000; path=/"
        ],
        "wrapper_type": "http",
        "stream_type": "tcp_socket/ssl",
        "mode": "rb",
        "unread_bytes": 0,
        "seekable": false,
        "uri": "https://sandbox.jiveon.com/api/core/v3/activities?after=2016-08-22T17:01:14%2b0000&count=500",
        "crypto": {
            "protocol": "TLSv1",
            "cipher_name": "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA",
            "cipher_bits": 256,
            "cipher_version": "TLSv1/SSLv3"
        },
        "timed_out": false,
        "blocked": true,
        "eof": false
    },
    "content": "",
    "status": 401,
    "success": false
}
```

By using https://requestb.in I can see that the PHP7 version does not include the Authorization header

What's changed between PHP 5.6.10 and PHP 7 to cause this? How do I fix it?

EDIT: Remove some red herring text and add Request Bin result.

Comment: For starters I see `"WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Jive SBS\""` in the PHP5 request but not the PHP7. I've never worked with this API so maybe you should get in touch with them. It's possible PHP7 is sending different headers which their API thinks is a hacking attempt?

Comment: Thanks. That gives me an idea. I'll try targeting the request at an endpoint i control and see what's different.

Comment: NP, one other thing to consider would be to use CURL instead of fopen() because it looks like you are simply interacting with a JSON API and fopen() is just a wrapper for CURL when dealing with URLs. I doubt that there is any benefit at all to using fopen() but I am not the expert so good luck!

Comment: Ok, so I've confirmed that PHP7 isn't sending the Authorization header, yet it is included in the context. I also tested a header of "foo:bar" and that's not passed through either.

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
protected function sendRequest($method, $url, $auth = null) {
    global $CFG;
    $options = func_num_args() === 4 ? func_get_arg(3) : array();

    $http = array(
      'max_redirects' => 0,
      'request_fulluri' => 1,
      'ignore_errors' => true,
      'method' => $method
    );

    $headers = array();

    if (!is_null($auth)) {
      array_push($headers, 'Authorization: ' . $auth);
    }

    if (($method === 'PUT' || $method === 'POST') && isset($options['content'])) {
      $http['content'] = $options['content'];
      array_push($headers, 'Content-length: ' . strlen($options['content']));
      array_push($headers, 'Content-Type: application/json');
    }

    $http['header'] = $headers;

    $context = stream_context_create(array( 'http' => $http ));

    var_dump(stream_context_get_options($context));echo('<hr/>');
    $fp = fopen($url, 'rb', false, $context);
    if (! $fp) {
      throw new \Exception('Request failed: $php_errormsg');
    }
    $metadata = stream_get_meta_data($fp);
    $content  = stream_get_contents($fp);
    $responseCode = (int)explode(' ', $metadata['wrapper_data'][0])[1];

    fclose($fp);

    return array (
      'metadata' => $metadata,
      'content' => $content,
      'status' => $responseCode
    );
  }
```

I'm now storing all the headers in an array variable and setting the header property to that.

I'm not 100% sure why but I think it has something to do with variable references. In one iteration of the code the $http authorization property was being marked with an ampersand by var_dump and that was being ignored by fopen. Another iteration which removed that ampersand worked.

Comment: See also https://github.com/RusticiSoftware/TinCanPHP/pull/72#issuecomment-241751758